# Problem with array script

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i want to give anchor tag to an image while checking the condition in slide show where my slide show is displayed using script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var res; 
    var hdnvalue = a = document.getElementById('HiddenField4').value;
    var imgArr = hdnvalue.split(';'); 

    var sp = [];

    for (var count = 0; count < imgArr.length; count++) {    
         sp.push([imgArr[count], "", "", ""]);    
    }  

    var mygallery2 = new fadeSlideShow({    
      wrapperid: "fadeshow2",    
      dimensions: [568, 313],    
      imagearray: sp,    

      displaymode: {    
        type: 'auto',    
        pause: 2500,    
        cycles: 0,    
        wraparound: false    
    },

    persist: false,    
    fadeduration: 500,    
    descreveal: "always",    
    togglerid: "fadeshow2toggler"

  })

</script>
```

in this script i want to check the condition

```
   'hdnLink' value->http://dev1.maxnet-tech.com/royalindustries/ProductList.aspx?s=4&sss1=17&sss2=3;;;

    var cnLink = document.getElementById('hdnLink').value;        
    var cnSplit = cnLink.split(';');        
    var b = a.split(';');


if (cnSplit[0] != "") {    
       then add <a>tag th that image which is redirected to plroduclist page    
}    
else {    
       add img     
}
```

how can i add  tag to  image acc to condition in an array like above script

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell the value of **document.getElementById('HiddenField4').value**?

As per my assumption of the value, this can be solution

> for (var count = 0; count <
>   imgArr.length; count++) {
>                 if(imgArr[count] != ''){
>
> ```
>   var str = "<a href='URL to redirect'><img src='imgArr[count]'> border='0' /></a>";
> ```
>
> }     else{
>
> ```
>   var str = "<a href='URL to > redirect'><img src='imgArr[count]' > border='0' /></a>";
> ```
>
> }
>   sp.push([str
>   , "", "", ""]);
>
> ```
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer
change sp.push([imgArr[count], "", "", ""]);     to
sp.push([imgArr[count], "http://www.gmail.com", "", ""]);

because the second parameter in this will be the link
bye